# Use of comma after "accidentally"

Tags: punctuation, adverbs, commas

Is a comma required after *accidentally*?

> I **accidentally** sent you the wrong number.

Comment: No, it's not even desired.  I think the only way I'd put commas in that sentence is to put one both before and after 'accidentally'. But I think it's better without any.

Comment: What makes you think so? That may explain the question. Voting to close.

Answer (score 3):

No, you must NOT put a comma here.  Fowler's Modern English Usage has this to say.

> Separating inseparables, e.g. a verb from its subject or object or complement ... *(and several examples follow)* ... In the foregoing examples the commas are manifestly wrong.

Answer (score 0):

In that sentence you should not add a comma after *accidentally*. The following sentence uses a comma, but that doesn't mean a comma is always used after *accidentally*.

> Accidentally, I gave you the wrong number.

Answer (score 0):

If the accidental nature of the action needs stressing, the adverb could be set off as a parenthetical, but brackets or more probably dashes would be used:

I – *accidentally* – sent you the wrong number.

(Italics to mark stress.)

If the statement is a response to a vexed question, the adverb would be best moved to terminal position:

I sent you the wrong number *accidentally*.